# Appending a string to a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

How can I append a string by adding '.' onto a UITextField? I have tried this: `[textfield.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];` but I am getting strange behavior - it converts the last character into a `.` instead of adding on. (I also use this code to add 0-9 chars and it works perfectly.)

Any other methods of appending the `.` and/or an explanations for this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to do `textfield.text = [textfield.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];` since the `stringByAppendingString:` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the existing one (as strings are immutable by default).

Comment: It still does it .. if i add '1234567' in the textbox, press the 'dot' button, i will have '123456.' =(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", textfield.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift

CommentTextField.text = CommentTextField.text?.stringByAppendingString(string)